# Adjust index for HTML string to compensate for HTML tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Suppose I have a function that returns the starting index (4) of the word 'world' in this HTML string:

```
<div>The world is round</div>
```

This function (outside of my control) works by using jQuery's `.text()` method. However, I need to use jQuery's `.html()` method for what I'm doing.

Using the existing index will give me the letter "n" from the span when using jQuery's `.html()` method. I need to alter this index to take account of additional HTML tags and nested HTML tags that might be in the div e.g.

```
<div><p><span class="highlight">The</span></p> world is round</div>
```

So, this code snippet would return a new index of 42 for the first letter of 'world'. How would I go about doing this? Many thanks!

UPDATE: The code snippet would return the index INCLUDING the tags. I'm not looking to strip the tags. Thanks!

Comment: if you have <div><p>world<span class="highlight">The</span></p> world is round</div>, what should the function return?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strip HTML from Text JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript)

Comment: The function should return the index INCLUDING html tags. So, stripped of tags, the index is 4. When including tags, it is 42.

Comment: Why not just `.html().indexOf("world")` ?

Comment: Because there may be more than one instance of the same word, and that will only work on the first instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution, however it does have a caveat... if the user were to type '<' or '>', it would fail.

```
        // Loop variables
        var within_html_tag = false;
        var tag_incrementer = 0;
        var text_incrementer = 0;
        var current_object_html = current_object.html();           

        // Adjust starting index to take account of HTML tags
        for (var i = 0; i < current_object_html.length; i++)
        {
            // Handle characters representing start or end of HTML tags
            if (current_object_html[i] == "<") { within_html_tag = true; }
            if (current_object_html[i] == ">") { within_html_tag = false; tag_incrementer++ }

            // Increment counters (depending on type)
            if (within_html_tag) { tag_incrementer++; } else { text_incrementer++; }

            // Once the desired index is reached, append tag incrementer and exit
            if (text_incrementer == start_index) 
            { 
                // Adjust the starting index
                start_index = text_incrementer + tag_incrementer;

                // Handle end of sentences
                if (current_object_html.substr((text_incrementer + tag_incrementer) - 2, 2) == "</") { start_index += 7; }

                // Escape procedure
                break; 
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = sourceString.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"").indexOf("word");
```

Is this what you need? Previous version was extracting just the nth word, but upon closer reading it seemed that you needed the index of a specific word , excluding tags, right?

Comment: Sorry, I need the index INCLUDING tags. Thanks!

Comment: So , basically you need to convert the output of a function that returns the index 4, to the index of the same word in the context that includes html tags?

Comment: Yes. So, per my example, the index (excluding tags) is 4. When including tags, it is 42. 42 is the number I need. Thanks!

Comment: I should also point out that a given word may occur more than once in a string. Not sure this is relevant or not since we're going by indexes, but thought I'd mention it anyway :)